# Webrtc video call on android

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

I´ve set up a clone of this repo, and got it up and running at heroku:

https://github.com/dondido/webrtc-video-room

.. after trying about 15 others that I had various problems with. It works great under Windows in chrome and firefox, but when trying to access it with a webview on android in the app I´m developing (in B4A), I see only a grey screen. I do however manage to succesfully use https://appr.tc which is a very similar demo from google in the webview, so something should be amended in the android code. I think it relates to navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, but I really don´t know what needs to be changed for this to function. I´ve been sitting and comparing the git repo for mentioned appr.tc but can´t nail the part that I have to amend. I am aware that I can just clone the appr.tc repo instead, but this one also needs GAE, which I want to avoid.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your class which contains the webview object

Comment: Hi Abir,

Thanks. Here´s the class files from B4A related to webview. But like I said, without even touching B4A, if you go to https://appr.tc/ which is a demonstration of webrtc, on lollipop stock browser it works fine, but in Marshmallow not.

http://www.filedropper.com/webview

Comment: They are all `.class` file not `.Java` file. Another thing you have `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` right?

Comment: Yes i do, but in the meantime I´ve figured out that the issue seems to be with particular versions of webview used by some versions of Android. So on Lollipop I´ve had success, and on Marshmallow not. This can be tested on the stock browsers on these devices by simply checking whether if https://appr.tc has access to local cam or not.